# How do I fetch all of a users subscriptions using the php Youtube Api?

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm kinda lost at the moment. I want to use the Youtube Api to fetch all of a logged in users subscriptions, and display them as a list, but I'm completely lost. I was thinking of using a batch request, but I don't know how to even begin to implement it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Use [Zend Framework - YouTube Data API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.7/ru/zend.gdata.youtube.html). It does not require any authentication.

**USING**

1) Download `Zend Framework 1.12.3 Minimal` from http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest

2) Unpack `zip`. Copy folder `Zend` to your project folder( or only `Zend\Gdata`).

3) Include to your `index.php` ( for example ) class `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` :

```
<?php
   require_once 'Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php';

   $username = 'USERNAME'; // set need YouTube user

   $yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
   $subscriptionFeed = $yt->getSubscriptionFeed($username);

   foreach ($subscriptionFeed as $subscriptionEntry) {
      echo $subscriptionEntry->title->text . "\n";
   }

?>
```

**EDIT 1**

Using `Youtube API`.
Check in `php.ini`:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Than use:

```
$userID = 'YouTubeUsedId';
$url_api = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$userID.'/subscriptions?v=2';
$subs_content = file_get_contents($url_api);
```

After getting `xml` with subscriptions, use `DomDocument` (for example ) & get user list. Get tags according https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_subscriptions#Retrieving_subscriptions

**EDIT 2** (Notice)

By default, YouTube return only first 25 some rows from  Video feed. To do offset, use next:

```
$url='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$userID.'/subscriptions?start-index=25
                                                                    &max-results=25
                                                                    &v=2';
```

`start-index` define from index starting

`max-results` define offest ( NOTICE: max value = 50 ).

See more https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=it-IT&csw=1#max-resultssp

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather do it using the Youtube api, if that's possible. I've tried to mess around with the "my_uploads" example in the php api, but I can't find anything on the api site to tell me how to change it to retrieve subscribers, not uploads

Comment: @looserlf i updated answer. However, I would advise you to download class `Zend_Gdata_YouTube` for this. Its good wrapper.

Comment: really sorry for being a hassle, but your edit didn't really make it any clearer for me. I've never used zend before, and I'm still a bit confused. How do I start? Do I have to include files or reference anything before I do it?

Comment: @looserlf  see now. I hope,you will understand. It simple enough.

Comment: Great! I finally got it to work, but just one more small thing. When I try to load my own subscribers as a test, the code only loads up the first 25 channels, when I actually have much more than that. Is there a way to get around this limit, or is this to do with YouTube?

Comment: @looserlf what u use : YouTube API or Zend_Gdata_YouTube ?

Comment: Youtube Api, with `'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.$userID.'/subscriptions?v=2'`, but I have zend as a backup. Which one would be best?

Comment: @looserlf  well this is as you comfortably

Comment: Is there a way to get around this limit with either of them?

Comment: @looserlf yes,i found now. I am shall add  to answer. 5 minutes

Comment: Perfect! I finally got it all up and running. Thank you so much for all your help! Really appreciated!